# how to schedule sms oremail to sent with iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

is there ny way to fix the time at which a sms or email will be send automatically from iphone sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no access to SMS, you can only create a popup if you call "sms://0123456789" using UIApplication - If anyone could just send SMS when they wanted and in the background, imagine the troubles that would come up.

Answer (score 1):

Theres no way you can do that.

The way i suggest is to send the text and date to the server and do server side coding to send the mails at the given time ......

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: make a php code tht takes the data from the serverdbase and send mails automatically. Use cronjobs.and from your iPhone store the data in serverdBase.

Comment: i want to know more about core telephony which is my other question ,plz have a look if u have time

Comment: Please post it as new question.. u will surely get few answers ;)